# Heap Corruption error when calling C from R, can't find the source issue

Tags: r, c

UPDATE3: Problem is solved but I'm leaving the code here as-is for future reference--I've posted an answer below with the final state of the code in case people wanted to see the final product.

---

UPDATE2: Refactored to use `R_alloc` instead of `calloc` for automated cleanup. Unfortunately the problem persists.

UPDATE: If I add this line right before `UNPROTECT(1)`:

```
Rprintf("%p %p %p", (void *)rans, (void *)fm, (void *)corrs);
```

then the function executes with no corrupted heap error. Maybe there's a background garbage collection call that corrupts one of the pointers prior to execution finishing, resulting in a write to a garbage pointer? Important to note here that if I don't print out all three of the pointer addresses, the error comes back.

Also I'm running this on an M1 Mac and compiling with `clang` via `R CMD SHLIB`, in case Apple silicon is to blame.

---

I'm at my wits end trying to debug this issue, and I figured I'd turn to SO for help. I'm writing a function in C to optimize some parts of my R code, and I'm getting a Heap Corruption Error when running the function many times. The function `trimCovar()` is called from R using the `.Call("trimCovar", ...)` interface.

I'm having a lot of difficulty debugging this for a few reasons:

1. I'm on OSX, so I can't use Valgrind
2. C function depends on inputs from R, so I can't debug the C code on its own
3. Heap corruption only occurs when calling the function many times within an R function
   (just running `.Call` directly a bunch of times has no errors)
4. Error point is inconsistent

I start with two sets of vectors, and I condense them into a frequency matrix, where each column is a position in the vector set, and each row is a particular character that appears. I concatenate them into one matrix prior to passing in because it makes pre-processing easier. An toy example of the frequency matrix would be:

```
INPUT:             
  v1_1 = 101
  v1_2 = 011

  v2_1 = 111
  v2_2 = 110

Frequency Matrix:

position: | 1_1 | 1_2 | 1_3 | 2_1 | 2_2 | 2_3 |

0:          0.5   0.5   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.5
1:          0.5   0.5   1.0   1.0   1.0   0.5
```

The goal is to find the `NV` highest correlated positions across the vector sets, which I do by calculating pairwise KL divergence of positions. These are stored in a linked list sorted in ascending order, and at the end I take the positions corresponding to the first `NV` entries. The R code I have can deparse everything else, so I really just need a vector of positions at the end (duplicates are allowed).

The function takes in 5 arguments:

- fMAT: a frequency matrix (RObject, so gets read in as a flat vector)
- fSP : columns in matrix corresponding to positions from the first vector set
- sSP : same as fSP but for second vector set
- NV  : Number of values to return
- NR  : Number of columns in fMAT

The error returned is:

```
R(95564,0x104858580) malloc: Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged at 0x600000f10040
*** Incorrect guard value: 4626885667169763328
R(95564,0x104858580) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

This only happens when I run an R function that calls this 10+ times, so I'm assuming that I'm just missing one or two small hanging pointers corrupting a memory reference. I've tried running this with `gc()` called in R immediately after each call, but it doesn't fix the problem. I'm not really sure what else to do at this point, I've tried using `lldb` but I'm not really sure how to use that program. From running lots of print statements I've determined that it usually crashes in the main loop (identified in code below), but it's inconsistent on when it crashes. I've also tried saving off erroneous inputs--I can rerun them individually with no issues, so it must be something relatively small that only appears over many runs.

Happy to provide more details if it would help. Code is listed at the bottom.

The only thing being allocated here are linked list nodes, and I thought I had `free()`'d them all prior to returning. I've also double checked the input values, so I'm 99.99% sure that I'm never referencing out of bounds on `firstSeqPos`, `secondSeqPos`, `ans`, or `fm`. I've also triple checked the R code surrounding this and can confidently say it is not the source of this error.

I haven't coded in C in a long time so I feel like I'm missing something obvious. If I really have to I can try to get ahold of a Linux box to run valgrind, but if there's another option I'd prefer it. Thanks in advance!

Code:

```c
#include <R.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct node {
  double data;
  int i1;
  int i2;
  struct node *next;
} node;

// Linked list
// data is the correlation value,
// i1 the position from first vector set,
// i2 the position from second vector set
node *makeNewNode(double data, int i1, int i2){
  node *newNode; 
  newNode = (node *)R_alloc(1, sizeof(node));
  newNode->data = data;
  newNode->i1 = i1;
  newNode->i2 = i2;
  newNode->next = NULL;
  return(newNode);
}

//insert link in sorted order (ascending)
void insertSorted(node **head, node *toInsert, int maxSize) {
  int ctr = 0;
  if ((*head) == NULL || (*head)->data >= toInsert->data){
    toInsert->next = *head;
    *head = toInsert;
  } else {
    node *temp = *head;
    while (temp->next != NULL && temp->next->data < toInsert->data){
      temp = temp->next;
      if (ctr == maxSize){
        // Performance optimization, if we aren't inserting in the first NR
        // positions then we can just skip since we only care about the NR 
        // lowest scores overall
        return;
      }
      ctr += 1;
    }
    toInsert->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = toInsert;
  }
}

// MAIN FUNCTION CALLED FROM R
// (This is the one that crashes)
SEXP trimCovar(SEXP fMAT, SEXP fSP, SEXP sSP, SEXP NV, SEXP NR){
  // Converting input SEXPs into C-compatible values
  int nv = asInteger(NV);
  int nr = asInteger(NR);
  int sp1l = length(fSP);
  int sp2l = length(sSP);

  int *firstSeqPos = INTEGER(coerceVector(fSP, INTSXP));
  int *secondSeqPos = INTEGER(coerceVector(sSP, INTSXP));
  double *fm = REAL(fMAT);
  int colv1, colv2;

  // Using a linked list for efficient insert
  node *corrs = NULL;
  int cv1, cv2;
  double p1, p2, score=0;

  // USUALLY FAILS IN THIS LOOP
  for ( int i=0; i<sp1l; i++ ){
    cv1 = firstSeqPos[i];
    colv1 = (cv1 - 1) * nr;
    for ( int j=0; j<sp2l; j++ ){
      cv2 = secondSeqPos[j];
      colv2 = (cv2 - 1) * nr;

      // KL Divergence
      score = 0;
      for ( int k=0; k<nr; k++){
        p1 = fm[colv1 + k];
        p2 = fm[colv2 + k];
        if (p1 != 0 && p2 != 0){
          score += p1 * log(p1 / p2);
        }
      }
      // Add result into LL
      node *newNode = makeNewNode(score, cv1, cv2);
      insertSorted(&corrs, newNode, nv);
    }
    R_CheckUserInterrupt();
  }
  SEXP ans;
  PROTECT(ans = allocVector(INTSXP, 2*nv));
  int *rans = INTEGER(ans); 
  int ctr=0;
  int pos1, pos2;
  node *ptr = corrs;

  for ( int i=0; i<nv; i++){
    rans[2*i] = ptr->i1;
    rans[2*i+1] = ptr->i2;
    ptr = ptr->next;
  }

  UNPROTECT(1);
  return(ans);
}
```

Comment: In `insertSorted`, should `head == NULL` be `*head == NULL`?

Comment: Oh yes it should--I fixed that, but unfortunately it doesn't fix the overall error. I'll edit the code to reflect that change though, thanks!

Comment: Note that heap corruption and memory leaks are two completely different problems.

Comment: Perhaps change `while ( ctr < nv )` to `while ( ptr != NULL && ctr < nv )`. Also, I'm not sure why you need the dummy node on the `corrs` list. You could just initialize `corrs` to be a null pointer, but then you might need to adjust the `ctr == maxsize` test to account for there no longer being a dummy node.

Comment: _Side note:_ If getting a linux box is difficult, you could try booting linux (e.g. ubuntu) under a VM (e.g. WSL/WSL2 or VirtualBox) to run `valgrind`. Or, maybe just compile with `-fsanitize=address` as the [native] versions of `gcc/clang` you're using should support that.

Comment: @FredLarson thanks for the comment--I'm historically an R/Python guy so I'm not super familiar with these kinds of bugs. I think I misunderstood what memory leaks are, but I've now looked it up and more or less get the difference. I'll adjust the question details to try to correct the terminology

Comment: @IanAbbott That's a great point, I'm not quite sure why I decided on this approach...I refactored it slightly to initialize `corrs` to a `NULL` pointer, and then I changed the `while(...)` to a `for` loop. Unfortunately the bug persists :(...Sidenote, thanks everyone for your comments, even though the bug hasn't been fixed yet the code is definitely better already!

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks for the tip! I also learned there's a [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-devel-san) that includes a pre-built R installation that supports ASan, so I'll look into that and using a VM like you mentioned later today.

Comment: Refactored the code to use `R_alloc` instead of `calloc` since it handles freeing memory automatically--I can now run this function 70-100 times before it crashes as opposed to 10-20 times previously. Problem is still there though :(

Comment: Just noticed Herve's answer. Glad you got your primary problem solved. But, I just noticed: In `insertSorted`, if you do the early "performance optimization" return (i.e. `ctr == maxSize`), you do _not_ free `toInsert`. The node is never linked to any list, so you can't free it later. So, you have a memory leak.

Comment: This code as written actually uses `R_alloc()`, which gives the responsibility of memory management to the R session. Once the function call finishes execution, the R session frees any memory allocated with `R_alloc()`, so no memory is leaked in this case. It isn't the most efficient solution though because that memory isn't freed until end of execution--I'm going to post an answer with the final code writeup in case people see this later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int *firstSeqPos = INTEGER(coerceVector(fSP, INTSXP));
int *secondSeqPos = INTEGER(coerceVector(sSP, INTSXP));
```

This is not good. The SEXPs returned by the 2 calls to `coerceVector()` need to be protected. However it's usually considered better practice to do this coercion at the R level right before entering the `.Call` entry point. Note that if `fSP` and `sSP` are integer matrices, there's no need to coerce them to integer as they are already seen as integer vectors at the C level. This also avoids a possibly expensive copy (`as.integer()` in R and `coerceVector()` in C *both* trigger a full copy of the matrix data).

Comment: Ahhh, that was the problem! These weren't protected, and so the garbage collector was cleaning them up prior to use, resulting in a corrupted heap. Thank you so much for your help, that worked!

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered above, but I received a couple messages from people asking for the final code, so I'm going to include it as an answer to preserve the original question. There's a couple optimizations here (thanks to [@hpages](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19038421/herv%C3%A9-pag%C3%A8s) for help and troubleshooting regarding these):

- Original code fails because the output of `coerceVector()` wasn't protected with `PROTECT()`. I've refactored the R code to check for integer inputs prior to calling this C function to avoid this function call and be more efficient with memory (see the accepted answer for more details).
- Original code uses `R_alloc()`, which gives responsibility to R to clean up memory at the end of the function call. However, this introduces substantial memory overhead during the runtime of the function, since memory allocated to nodes not inserted into the linked list aren't cleared until the end of the function call.
- Allocation with `calloc()` isn't as simple as switching over and calling `free()` at the end of the function, since we have to guard the case where the user interrupts execution of the program. If an interrupt signal is thrown prior to the end of the function, we'll never free the memory.

Final C Code:

```c
#include <R.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct node {
  double data;
  int i1;
  int i2;
  struct node *next;
} node;

// Defining the head as a static so that we can access it globally
// Important for ensuring clean up in case of interrupt
static node *corrs = NULL;

// Function to clean up memory allocations in case of interrupt
void cleanupFxn(){
  node *ptr = corrs;
  // Free allocated memory in linked list
  while (corrs != NULL){
    ptr = corrs;
    corrs = corrs->next;
    free(ptr);
  }
}

node *makeNewNode(double data, int i1, int i2){
  node *newNode; 
  // very important to use calloc here so we have control of when we free it
  // R_alloc() memory won't be freed until after function finishes execution
  newNode = (node *)calloc(1, sizeof(node));
  newNode->data = data;
  newNode->i1 = i1;
  newNode->i2 = i2;
  newNode->next = NULL;
  return(newNode);
}

// insert link in sorted order
// returns a bool corresponding to if we inserted
bool insertSorted(node **head, node *toInsert, int maxSize) {
  int ctr = 0;
  if ((*head) == NULL || (*head)->data >= toInsert->data){
    toInsert->next = *head;
    *head = toInsert;
    return(true);
  } else {
    node *temp = *head;
    while (temp->next != NULL && temp->next->data < toInsert->data){
      temp = temp->next;
      if (ctr == maxSize){
        // Performance optimization, if we aren't inserting in the first NR
        // positions then we can just skip since we only care about the NR 
        // lowest scores overall. Saves a huge amount of time and memory.
        return(false);
      }
      ctr += 1;
    }
    toInsert->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = toInsert;
    return(true);
  }
}

SEXP trimCovar(SEXP fMAT, SEXP fSP, SEXP sSP, SEXP NV, SEXP NR){
  // Converting inputs into C-compatible forms
  int nv = asInteger(NV);
  int nr = asInteger(NR);
  int sp1l = length(fSP);
  int sp2l = length(sSP);

  // Note here we're not using coerceVector() anymore
  // typechecking done on R side
  int *firstSeqPos = INTEGER(fSP);
  int *secondSeqPos = INTEGER(sSP);
  double *fm = REAL(fMAT);
  int colv1, colv2;
  
  // Using a linked list for efficient insert
  corrs = NULL;
  int cv1, cv2;
  double p1, p2, score=0;
  bool success;
  for ( int i=0; i<sp1l; i++ ){
    cv1 = firstSeqPos[i];
    colv1 = (cv1 - 1) * nr;
    for ( int j=0; j<sp2l; j++ ){
      cv2 = secondSeqPos[j];
      colv2 = (cv2 - 1) * nr;

      score = 0;
      for ( int k=0; k<nr; k++){
        p1 = fm[colv1 + k];
        p2 = fm[colv2 + k];
        if (p1 != 0 && p2 != 0){
          score += p1 * log(p1 / p2);
        }
      }
      node *newNode = makeNewNode(score, cv1, cv2);
      success = insertSorted(&corrs, newNode, nv);
      // If we don't insert, free the associated memory
      // I'm checking for NULL here just out of an abundance of caution
      if (!success && newNode != NULL){
        free(newNode);
        newNode = NULL;
      }
    }
    R_CheckUserInterrupt();
  }


  SEXP ans;
  PROTECT(ans = allocVector(INTSXP, 2*nv));
  int *rans = INTEGER(ans); 
  node *ptr=corrs;

  for ( int i=0; i<nv; i++){
    rans[2*i] = ptr->i1;
    rans[2*i+1] = ptr->i2;
    ptr = ptr->next;
  }

  // Free allocated memory in linked list
  cleanupFxn();

  UNPROTECT(1);
  return(ans);
}
```

Assuming the C file is named `trimCovar.c`, we'd compile with `R CMD SHLIB trimCovar.c`.

R Code to run this function:

```
dyn.load("trimCovar.so")

# Wrapped into a function with on.exit(...) to ensure cleanup
# in the event the user or system interrupts execution early
CorrComp_C <- function(fm, fsp, ssp, nv, nr){
  # type checking to ensure input to C is integer vector
  # (could probably do more type checking here, mainly for illustration)
  stopifnot(is(fsp, 'integer'))
  stopifnot(is(ssp, 'integer'))
  on.exit(.C("cleanupFxn"))
  a <- .Call('trimCovar', fm, fsp, ssp, nv, nr)
  return(a)
}
```

Comment: Note that the nice thing about using `on.exit(.C("cleanupFxn"))` for clean up is that cleanup will happen _no matter what_ i.e. not only on user interrupt but only on normal termination or in case of error. So you don't need to call `cleanupFxn()` explicitly at the end of `trimCovar()`. Also you should check the pointer returned by `calloc(1, sizeof(node))`. If NULL, then you can immediately `error()`. Again, `on.exit(.C("cleanupFxn"))` will take care of the cleanup.

Comment: Nit: The comment "very important to use calloc here so we have control of when we free it[,]  R_alloc() memory won't be freed until after function finishes execution" is correct but pointless. You can use `R_Calloc()` alongside `R_Free`, see https://rstudio.github.io/r-manuals/r-exts/The-R-API.html#user-controlled-memory

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel yep, the comment was more in reference to using `calloc` over `R_alloc`, not `calloc` over `R_Calloc`

Comment: @HervéPagès makes sense, I had included it for completeness but it does add an unnecessary function call. I’ll make that fix to the `calloc` call